# Trouble estimating gas cost of function in Remix console

Tags: remix, gas-estimate

I'm trying to follow a tutorial for estimating the gas cost of a function.

https://cristian.io/post/estimate-gas/


Thus after deploying my contract I type in this code in the Remix console to get the gas estimate of calling an arbitrary funtion (substituting in my contract details):

```
var contractABI = [ ... ];
var contractAddress = '0xxxxx';

var contract = web3.eth.contract(contractABI);
var contractInstance = contract.at(contractAddress);

var estimatedGas = contractInstance._mint.estimateGas('0x123', '5');
```

I get this response in the Remix console window:

```
Cannot read property 'estimateGas' of undefined
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or is Remix unable to fully utilize web3 in the console?

Comment: What version of web3 are you using? It seems it is web3 v0.20. Is `_mint` a public or external function in your contract?

Comment: It's an internal function; and I'm just using the web3 version that is in the Remix console down at the bottom of the page.

Comment: You cannot call an internal function from javascript, and estimateGas will fail.